Aspire KeyVault configuration provider azd deploy manifest
This is a follow-up question to Aspire KeyVault configuration provider and AddAzureKeyVaultSecrets.
In the AppHost/Program.cs there's the following switch between KeyVault and a regular database connection string:
var secrets = builder.ExecutionContext.IsPublishMode
    ? builder.AddAzureKeyVault("VaultUri")
    : builder.AddConnectionString("MyDbConnectionString");

builder.AddProject<Projects.My_Web>("webfrontend")
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints()
    .WithReference(secrets);

In the Web/Program.cs the KV value is run when we are away from the local development environment:
if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVaultSecrets("VaultUri");
}

The AppHost/appsettings.json have the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration configuration:
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbConnectionString": "Server=my.database.windows.net,3342;Database=DEV;user id=User;password='password123'",
  },
  "Aspire": {
    "Azure": {
      "Security": {
        "KeyVault": {
          "VaultUri": "https://kvdev.vault.azure.net/",
          "DisableHealthChecks": false,
          "DisableTracing": true,
          "ClientOptions": {
            "DisableChallengeResourceVerification": true
          }
        }
      },
    }
  }

We get the db connection string okay when running locally.
The issue is that when publishing the param for the AddAzureKeyVault is being prepended to the key in the configuration provider so that azd deploy is reporting:

executing "manifest template" at <.Env.VAULTURI_VAULTURI>: map has no entry for key "VAULTURI_VAULTURI"

I think there's a problem with .NET Aspire using the required name in the AddAzureKeyVault and adding that to the key in the configuration which it should have by default. More likely I've misunderstood these strings and I need to do this differently.
Should I abandon the configuration provider, Aspire:Azure:Security:KeyVault?

You likely don't need to abandon the configuration provider, but ensure that you're passing the correct environment variables and not doubling the VaultUri key in the AddAzureKeyVault configuration. Verify that the configuration provider is reading the correct value for the VaultUri without accidental string duplication, especially when deploying with azd.
